# How to override connectedCallback and other functions for every element on a page

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-component, custom-element

I'm wanting to create a user-customizable web-app made with web-components. I'd like to be able to add hooks into the custom-element lifecycle for users and developers to hook into. I could add hooks into the lifecycle of individual components, but that reduces interoperability of the web-components. Is there a way to override whatever is calling connectedCallback() and other custom-element functions so that I can call hooks on any and every element on the page?

That way users can bring in whatever web-components they wish, but there is still a standard way for plugins to hook in.

So far, I haven't even been able to find out where or what or how connectedCallback() and the other custom-element functions get called. So I don't know what functions to override. This project is still very theoretical. I'm wanting to know if it is even possible to do something like that.

Comment: You can hijack ``customElements`` (if you can 'get in' soon enough) But *"there is still a standard way for plugins to hook in."* will always be **your** standard way.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Yes. By 'standard way', I mean standard across the project and its ecosystem regardless of where the custom elements come from. I'm thinking my approach is probably wrong. I need to come at it from a different angle, maybe using bind to redefine all the functions of the custom elements themselves to include a hook invocation prior to calling the original function and a hook invocation after calling the original function. I think that I can get some traction with that approach.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?